# How To Fetch Records using MySQL With Multiple Min and Max Conditions?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Table looks

```
StudentId, SubjcetName, Marks
1          Maths        50
1          Science      80
1          Language     70
2          Maths        80
2          Science      50
2          Language     60
3          Maths        85
3          Science      95
3          Language     60
```

From this table i want fetch records - Who got marks in Maths Min:50 and Max:90 and also who got marks below 75 in Science.

I Excepted results

```
1 Maths 50
2 Maths 80
2 Science 50
3 Maths 85
```

How to form a query to get the result?

Note: Subjects are dynamic and also min and max can be applicable to any subject.

Comment: SELECT StudentId, SubectName,Marks, (CASE WHEN SubectName='Maths' THEN Marks ELSE END) as MathsMarks, (CASE WHEN SubectName='Science' THEN Marks ELSE END) as ScienceMarks, (CASE WHEN SubectName='Language' THEN Marks ELSE END) as LanguageMarks FROM StundetTable WHERE Status'Active' HAVING MathsMarks >=50 AND MathsMarks <=90 AND ScienceMarks <=75``` Writing query is right method ? Please let me know any good way to write a better way to get the results

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(SELECT StudentId, SubjcetName, Marks 
FROM table
WHERE SubjcetName = 'Maths'
AND Marks BETWEEN 50 AND 90)
UNION
(SELECT StudentId, SubjcetName, Marks 
FROM table
WHERE SubjcetName = 'Science'
AND Marks < 75)
```

Comment: Thanks,  Any other ways there? Because if more number of subjects then it will be more number of Union Query.  On top of this i have filter condition StudentId ans Status, etc

Comment: Expected Results: [StudentId, SubjcetName, Marks
1          Maths        50
1          Science      80
1          Language     70
2          Maths        80
2          Science      50
2          Language     60]

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query ,

```
 SELECT StudentId, SubjcetName, Marks  FROM tablename
 WHERE Marks BETWEEN 50 AND 90
 AND SubjcetName="Maths"
 OR
(Marks < 75 AND SubjcetName="Science")
```

It is work for me.

Comment: i think, This query won't work when we apply more filter condtions. Because "or" will fetch the records if one conditions satisfied

Comment: Please put "or" condition at last of all conditions

Comment: SELECT studentid, subjectname, marks ,status FROM student
 WHERE marks BETWEEN 50 AND 90
 AND subjectname="maths"
 AND studentid="1"
 AND status="Active"
 OR
(marks < 75 AND subjectname="science" AND studentid="2" AND status="Active")

Comment: may be this can help

Comment: Thanks @hetal gohel, Here one more challenge is there, if conditions is match then for those students need to fetch the all the subjects marks.  student 1 and student 2

Comment: I Excepted results: `1          Maths        50
1          Science      80
1          Language     70
2          Maths        80
2          Science      50
2          Language     60`